# JDialog with JTextFields gets blocked after switching windows, JRE 7, 8 and OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, swing, focus, jtextfield

I’m developing in Java 8 and swing for OSX Maverics, I have a modal `JDialog` with text text fields, when I use “mission control”, and switch to other window and then come back, I found all my text fields blocked and neither “actívate” or “focusGained” of the `JDialog are called, it doesn’t happen if a I switch using “command+tab”, or in any version of windows.

I can't regain focus of the dialog or the boxes even clicking on then several times, at that stage the only choice is to close a reopen the dialogs or switch away and back again but using command+tab, that unlocks the `JDialog` again.

The `JDialog` is called from a `JFrame` that is registered as it's parent.

So far I've tried calling the modal window from `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait();` even nested, as suggested in other thread, I've tried several look and feels with the same result, this issue happens even in Netbeans windows and the Java's modality examples found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

I already tried @camickr solution, (even knowing it was for a different problem).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

TEST CODE, Remember to switch windows using mission control (Ctrl+Up).

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JDialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Frm().setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Frm extends JFrame{

        public Frm() throws Exception {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Show modal");
            add(btn);
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Dlg(Frm.this).setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            setSize(300, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }        
    }

    static class Dlg extends JDialog{

        public Dlg(JFrame parent) {
            super(parent, true);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
            add(new JTextField());
            add(new JLabel("Switch to other window using Mission Control (Ctrl+Up)"));
            add(new JLabel("Switch back to this window using Mission Control (Ctrl+Up)"));
            add(new JLabel("Try to write something in the text field"));
            setSize(350, 150);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't encountered any regression in this area. Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem; this would allows others to report their results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest, I'll post the mcve in a few hours.